# Sphere turned inside out

Tags: differential-topology

How can I turn a sphere inside out?
I saw this video on YouTube and I didn't understood how can i turn a sphere inside out.
any help will be appreciated.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video, of course, is not a proof. You can find references to several rigorous proofs (including the original one) at [Smale's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale%27s_paradox) ("References" section).